# Dotnetbar Slide Panel - Resizing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetbar

I am using dotnetbar with visual studio 2010.

I added dotnetbar slide panel to form. When a button is clicked, the panel slides-in & when cancel button pressed, the panel slides out.
But, when the form is maximized or re-sized, the slide panel not change it's size.
Slide panel anchor mode is left+right+top+bottom (I don't need it in filled dock mode).

Also, if we run the form & maximize the form while the slide panel is visible, then it locks to it's anchor points & maximizes. If we maximize the form while the slide panel invisible, it can't detect the form size & not anchoring.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem and this is how I solved it.

First you must calculate the difference between the rectangle of the form and the slidepanel like you have to consider the original location x,y of the object.

After this in the resize event of the form, add the following

```
If Not SlidePanel1.IsOpen Then
    SlidePanel1.OpenBounds = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(OriginalX, OriginalY, Me.DisplayRectangle.Width - DifferenceWidth, Me.DisplayRectangle.Height - DifferenceHeight)
End If
```

`OriginalX`, `OriginalY`, `DifferenceWidth` and `DifferenceHeight` are variables and constants which you must declare or set manually.

Comment: i have same problem but still cannot get this work, could you help bit here? Let me know if you still there.